# Values from letters in Java

Tags: java, methods, character

I have an assignment for my Java class where I need to code multiple methods in one program. For the most part I understand everything except one where I am suppose to get the values between 2 letters. Here is the directions "Create a method that is passed 2 letters, then prints all the values between the first letter and the second letter, inclusive. When the first letter passed comes after the second letter alphabetically, swap the values before printing. Call the method using any two UPPERCASE letters." And this is what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char first = 'A';
    char last = 'Z'; 
    printLetters(first,last);
}//end main

public static void printLetters(char a, char z){
    char temp;
    if(a < b){
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }//end if
    while(a <= b)
        a++;
}//end printLetters
```

So basically I am lost as to how I am suppose to get values from letters and then how I am to code it so it performs what I'm asked to do which is print all the values between the 2 letters. I am a beginner and methods already have my head spinning, but this has me completely stumbling in the dark.

Comment: Cast from char to int like so: `(int)'A'`. Cast from int to char like so: `(char)30`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had the right idea, except for a few minor errors:

1. You called the second parameter `z` but kept referencing `b`.
2. Your check if `a < b` should be `a > b`.
3. Since you want to print only the values between both letters, your `while` loop should use `<`, not `<=`.
4. And you forgot to actually print the letter

So:

```
public static void printLetters(char a, char b) { //1st comment
    char temp;
    if (a > b) { // 2nd comment
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }//end if
    while (a < b) { // 3rd comment
        a++;
        System.out.println(a); // 4th comment
    }
}//end printLetters
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you are doing it right,you just need to do

```
public static void printLetters(char a, char b){
    char temp;
    if(a > b){
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }//end if
     while(a <= b)
        System.out.print((char)a++);
}//end printLetters
```

this is called as casting because when you do 'a++' internally java does addition of ASCII value of character 'a' which results in integer value, so you need to cast it back to character form

Comment: so i did that, but the program is still not printing anything

Answer (score 0):

Your printletters method takes parameters `a` and `z`, but the code inside uses `a` and `b`.  You can fix that by changing printletters to:

```
printLetters(char a, char b) {
```